# Hyperlinks in ICML-example-file don't work in Overleaf, but work in AdobeReader

Tags: hyperref, overleaf

In this Overleaf-project: https://www.overleaf.com/read/swqsztcttswn clicking on hyperlinks in Overleaf has not the desired effect<sup>1)</sup>, but when I download the pdf, the hyperlinks work in Adobe Reader.

I tested it in Firefox 72.0.2 and Google Chrome---in both clicking hyperlinks does not have the desired effect.

https://www.overleaf.com/read/swqsztcttswn is just copy and paste from the official website of a very popular conference ICML: https://media.icml.cc/Conferences/ICML2020/Styles/icml2020_style.zip (this is an example file that should show how one should write a paper)

Did I something wrong or do other people experience the same problem?

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

<sup>1)</sup>When I click the hyperlink a little box is drawn around the hyperlink and in the lower left corner Firefox shows the correct(?) url `https://www.overleaf.com/read/swqsztcttswn#subsubsection.2.3.2`, but the view doesn't jump to another position---nothing moves.

Comment: I will not go to an overleaf project or download large style files to investigate your problem. You should add a small complete example here.  But the standard reason that hyperlinks don't work is that the code doesn't load hyperref (adobe reader often simply guess that something is a link).

Comment: It looks like a (small) bug in the Overleaf viewer, you could consider sending a bug report to them.

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ Moving `\usepackage{hyperref}` to _after_ `\usepackage{icml2020}` would also make the hyperlinks work in the Overleaf preview panel (pdf.js).

Comment: @LianTzeLim Thanks, but moving it results in changing the link colors: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xghrqmwfjtqj

Comment: Then another alternative to Marijn's answer: turn off `FitH` after loading `icml2000`, e.g. in this sequence: `\usepackage{hyperref}\usepackage{icml2020}\hypersetup{pdfview={XYZ}}` as in https://www.overleaf.com/read/wwnjprndrfjh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ICML style sets `pdfview=FitH` in the options to hyperref using the `\hypersetup` command. For some reason this confuses the Overleaf PDF viewer. Switching the option off makes the link work:

```
% line 94 in icml2020.sty
\ifdefined\nohyperref\else\ifdefined\hypersetup
  \definecolor{mydarkblue}{rgb}{0,0.08,0.45}
  \hypersetup{ %
    pdftitle={},
    pdfauthor={},
    pdfsubject={Proceedings of the International Conference on Machine Learning 2020},
    pdfkeywords={},
    pdfborder=0 0 0,
    pdfpagemode=UseNone,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=mydarkblue,
    citecolor=mydarkblue,
    filecolor=mydarkblue,
    urlcolor=mydarkblue,
    %pdfview=FitH
}
```

Note that the Overleaf viewer is only intended as a preview of the output for yourself and your co-authors, so if some features don't work in the preview it is not really a big problem - once the paper is reviewed and (hopefully) published other people will not use Overleaf to read it.

Comment: works great: https://www.overleaf.com/read/njyqvyxvrtxn
Do you think I should report this to ICML or to Overleaf or to pdf.js?

Comment: @Jakob I would report it to Overleaf, they can decide who is responsible and forward the bug to the viewer developers if needed.

Comment: Thanks! I'll pass this on to our engineers.